# Asymptotic evaluation of integral of algebraic function

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I am wondering what techniques exist for the asymptotic evaluation of integrals. Consider the integral
$$
I(\lambda) = \int_1^\lambda dx \sqrt{1-\frac 1 x} =  \sqrt \lambda \sqrt{\lambda - 1}- \cosh^{-1} \sqrt \lambda .
$$
It is clear from the explicit expression that $I(\lambda) \approx \lambda - \frac 1 2\log(4 \lambda) - \frac 1 2$ for large $\lambda$. Could we have found this asymptotic solution without explicitly evaluating the integral? I am familiar only with the steepest descent method, but it does not appear to be applicable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier than steepest descent : just analyse the main behaviour of the integrand, guess where the main contribution is coming from and what shape it takes, substract it, and iterate. Call $I_1(\lambda)$ your integral :
$$I_1(\lambda) = \int_1^\lambda \sqrt{1-1/x}\ {\rm d}x .$$
The integrand is $\sim 1$ as $x\to\infty$, so that
$$ I_1(\lambda) = \lambda - 1 + \underbrace{\int_1^\lambda (\sqrt{1-1/x}-1){\rm d}x}_{I_2(\lambda)}. $$
Then the integrand in $I_2(\lambda)$ is $\sim -1/(2x)$ as $x\to\infty$, so that
$$ I_2(\lambda) = -\frac12\int_1^\lambda\frac{{\rm d} x}x + \underbrace{\int_1^\lambda \big(\sqrt{1-1/x}-1+1/(2x)\big){\rm d}x}_{J_3(\lambda)}. $$
The integrand in $J_3$ is $O(1/x^2)$ for large $x$, so $J_3(\lambda)$ converges to a constant as $\lambda\to\infty$. Write
$$ J_3(\lambda) = \int_1^\infty \big(\sqrt{1-1/x}-1+1/(2x)\big){\rm d}x - \int_\lambda^\infty \big(\sqrt{1-1/x}-1+1/(2x)\big){\rm d}x .$$
Then you can go on with the asymptotic expansion in the same way (the integrand is $\sim c/x^2$, that gives you a term of size $c/\lambda$, etc...) It's a general fact that you won't usually get a nice, explicit expression for the "constant term" in that way.

Comment: Can you explain why we do not get the constant term? Is there no other way to get the constant term? What if the constant term is the leading term?

Comment: You do get the constant term, but it is usually not explicit : here, it is the integral $C = \int_1^\infty (\sqrt{1-1/x}-1+1/(2x)){\rm d}x$. It so happens that we can evaluate it to $-\ln(2)+1/2$. For your second question, consider $J_3(\lambda)$ above. The "constant term" is the leading term, it is the limit as $\lambda\to\infty$ (that's $C$). The procedure is then the same : you substract it, and analyze the remainder (that's the last line).